# Adding M0, M1, ... Mn between each two elements in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to loop through a list, which is called **output** as shown below:

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

But I have to exclude the first and last elements `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Then I would like to add between each two elements M. *For the first two elements M0, the second two elements M1 and so on*.

x= `[1, M0, 2, M1, 3, M2, 4, M3, 5]`

***The expected output =***

```
[[1, M0, 2],[2, M1, 3],[3, M2, 4],[4, M3, 5]]
```

And could I solve it with ***(while, for, and if)*** instead of using multiple for loops? Could you please assist me?

Below is my try:

## Python code:

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Total = []
for i in output:
    if i != output[0] and i != output[-1]:
        Total.append(i)
print(Total)
for j in (Total):
    print(j)

h = []
for x in Total:
    for y in (x,'M'0):
        h.append(y)
print(h)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution you can try, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create pairs & [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) over that.

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

output = output[1:-1] # Remove first & last digit

print(
    [[i, f'M{index}', j] for index, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(output, output[1:]))]
)
```

---

```
[[1, 'M0', 2], [2, 'M1', 3], [3, 'M2', 4], [4, 'M3', 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l = []
#remove the first and last element, you also can use pop(output.pop(0), output.pop(-1))
for i in output[1:-1]:
    l.append(i)
print(l)

i = 1
count=1
while i < len(l):
    adding = f'M{count}'
    l.insert(i, adding )
    i += 2
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `roundrobin()` function in either [the `more_itertools` module](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.roundrobin), or as [a recipe in the docs for the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Then you just need to construct the two lists — the original without the first and last elements, and the Mn sequence.

```
from more_itertools import roundrobin

output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
h = roundrobin(
    output[1:-1],
    ('M%d' % i for i in range(len(output) - 3)),
)

print(list(h))
```

Note that `roundrobin()` returns a generator; if you need to use it more than once, or if you want to print it out, convert the result to a `list`. If you're just going to iterate through it or otherwise use it just once, you can leave it as a generator.

Comment: Thank you so much dear, but could be solved without importing libraries please?

Comment: Use the [recipe in the `itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which only uses the standard library?

Comment: Sir, I mean I would like the code to be in the simplest form without libraries.

Comment: If you don't want to use `for` loops and don't want to use the standard library, what do you want to use?